# Is it a bad architectural choice to use both Varnish and elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, architecture, varnish

I have a REST service that users use and a Varnish cache in front of it to protect the database from too many requests.

A new requirement came by to be able to perform quick searches on the data set exposed by our service and we started using Elasticsearch for this purpose.

Is it a bad approach to keep both Varnish and Elastic? Should we use only Elasticsearch?

NOTE: the fact that Elastic is a NRT system is not an issue.

Thanks

Comment: So is it bad or good practice ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's a problem, just so long as you realize they are solving for different problems and you should probably not let varnish cache anything that you delegate to elasticsearch.

So our arch (super high level) looks something like load balancer > varnish > apache web machines

Those web machines have as a backend both elasticsearch and mysql (among other things).

Our site is largely broken down into two main areas 1.) homepage and similar, which is largely driven by a CMS and html rendered on the server. 2.) Single page web apps that have restful endpoints. The client is responsible for rendering their own HTML (we use react here).

For the heavier CMS stuff, we do varnish cache what we can. For anything that relies on elasticsearch, we let varnish pass on these requests. Our URL patterns for this kind of thing are predictable, so it's just one stanza in the varnish.vcl.

The idea being, search should be current. We also don't use ES much for the CMS type stuff, but more the single page web app stuff further into our site. The CMS stuff only changes a handful of times a day, but the SPA stuff has constant changes (around 25 index operations per second) across the cluster.

Comment: Curious why the recommendation to not use Varnish in front of Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Take this into account: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16024

Varnish strips out the JSON body of a GET request because it's invalid. So adding it directly in front of Elastic Search might give trouble. Adding a simple API in front of Elastic Search for your search queries might do the trick.